# Issue on Checkboxinput on the refreshing the main panel screen

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I have a shiny app that a user can check a box if he want to show the data and if so he can select the number of data tables to be displayed in the main panel. There are 2 action buttons, one for submit and refresh. If a user  selects 1 or 2 or 3 in the selectinput and hit submit.It will display the 3 datatables in the main panel. Once he hit refresh or unchecked the checkbox, it clears the main panel screen, however if he decided to check the box again, the last displayed table shows on the main panel. This should also clear the screen. How do I clear the screen if he checks the box again. Here is my code. Thank you for looking into  this I am new to R and Shiny

```
    library(shiny)
    library(DT)
    ui <- fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
        checkboxInput("addData", "Add Data"),
        conditionalPanel(condition="input.addData === true",
          selectInput("amountTable", "Amount Tables", 1:10),
          actionButton("submit1" ,"Submit", icon("refresh"),
                       class = "btn btn-primary"),

          actionButton("refresh1" ,"Refresh", icon("refresh"),
                       class = "btn btn-primary")
         )

        ),
      mainPanel(
       # UI output
       uiOutput("dt")
       )
      ) 
     )

   server <-  function(input, output, session) {

    global <- reactiveValues(refresh = FALSE)

    observe({
      if(input$refresh1) isolate(global$refresh <- TRUE)
    })

    observe({
      if(input$submit1) isolate(global$refresh <- FALSE)
    })

    observeEvent(input$submit1, {
       lapply(1:input$amountTable, function(amtTable) {
         output[[paste0('T', amtTable)]] <- DT::renderDataTable({
         iris[1:amtTable, ]
            })
     })
   })

   observeEvent(input$submit1, {

     lapply(1:input$amountTable, function(j) {
        output[[paste0('Text', j)]] <- renderText({
       paste0("This is AmountTable", j)
        # br()  ## add space in between the text and table
       })
    })
 })

 output$dt <- renderUI({  
   if(global$refresh) return()
     tagList(lapply(1:input$amountTable, function(i) {
       list(textOutput(paste0('Text', i)),br(),
           dataTableOutput(paste0('T', i)))
     }))
 })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: for me if i uncheck the box, the main screen does not get unchecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this code to you `server` function.

```
observe({
    if(input$addData == FALSE) isolate(global$refresh <- TRUE)
  })
```

This will remove the tables when you uncheck the `checkbox`

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You should use
`if(input$refresh1 | !input$addData) isolate(global$refresh <- TRUE)` instead of this line `if(input$refresh1) isolate(global$refresh <- TRUE)`

Edit: krish was faster. However, I leave the answer as is would shorten the code.